# Nokia Booklet 3G - Black Screen with underscore after Linux install

Tags: boot, lubuntu, mate, nokia

my computer is Nokia Booklet 3G. I've tried to install Lubuntu and Ubuntu Mate. Both end up in same situtation. When the installation is ready, in the end it asks do you want to restart computer, I press yes and the computer restarts. I end up with black screen with blinking underscore. This happens with both installations.

I've tried to reinstall Ubuntu Mate, but the installer crashes? (not sure how common is this yet).

I also tried to wipe the harddrive with DBAN but it was SUPER SLOW. My hard drive is 160 GB and it literally took 6 hours to get 5% done. HDtune says my harddrive is okay (tested with MiniXP on HBCD).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a different laptop.  Fact is, there are many laptops that reportedly won't let you install Ubuntu or other Linux Distro.  But the problem apparently isn't with Linux.

It's with Grub2.  There's something it does, or doesn't do. in the install process that cripples your PC.  Nobody has spelled this out yet, but there is an easy fix.

Download the Boot-Repair-Disk iso image file and burn it to a CD.  It should show up in a search of the internet.  After you've done a Linux install, reboot to this CD.  It will check your system, and if your laptop is like mine in this respect, it may tell you that it has to replace grub2.  I let it, and it later showed me on two screens the commands I had to enter in a terminal window to complete the job.  As I recall, you can copy and paste the commands.  You also have the option to open a terminal window while there.  The toolbar is on the bottom of the screen.

That was it.  I've had no problems in that regard since.  I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, which gave a black screen and blinking cursor right after I installed it.

It should not be necessary to wipe your hard drive.  In extreme cases, that means overwriting every part of the drive multiple times so as to virtually guarantee that whatever was there before is completely and utterly gone.  It should be enough just to format your hard drive, something that takes very little time with Linux because it does not do the whole drive, but only the part you need immediately.  Windows does it differently, so it takes a long time.  You have gparted (gnome partition editor) that you can run from the LiveCD for this purpose.  Or if going right into the install process, you can make changes to the hard drives and partitions as part of the install process by choosing the "Something else" choice that appears at the bottom of the page where you select the manner in which the install is to be done.

Best choice for what to set up your partition(s) as is generally accepted as ext4.  You need one pzrtition to be root, meaning make it "/".  If more than one partition, you can either ignore the others, or designate one or more to other root folders.  I usually only do one as root and let the installer just add the others to the same partition (default).

You need a swap partition as well,  I'd say 16GB would be a good sizem but some might go more or less.  It makes uo for insufficient RAM sometimes, but if you have to use it, your machine will be very slow.  It's better to have more RAM is possible.

160GB drive is not a whole lot.  For some people it would be more than enough.  But with Terabyte and more drives available for $85 and less, I would think seriously about replacing the one you have with a bigger one,  Just get the 2.5" size.  They all have the same connectors, you just remove a plate on the bottom of the laptop and take the old one out, stick the new one in its place and put the plate back on.  Takes less than 5 minutes.  With a Terabyte drive, you could divide it into three partitions equally sized at about 315GB, have a good swap partition with the remainder, and have three separate, identical or different, operating systems in place.  Gives you lots of room to play around or grow in.

Comment: I'll try to download the Repair disk later, I'll report with results. I can't even finish Linux install now, it crashes when I try it most of the time.

I'm probably updating to 32 GB SSD (cheap), instead of my slow 160 GB HDD. Is it worth it? The computer is really cheap and I don't wanna use money to it. Its almost impossible to upgrade my RAM (1GB) its soldered to the board.

I know my limits with space, and even 32 GB is enough for me, but is it enough for Linux? My computer only fits 1.8" drives, so they're rare. I know how to change hard drive and I'm experienced with computers overall.

Comment: While installing Ubuntu MATE, I ran in to this problem:

Installer Crashed (as superuser)
We're sorry; the installer crashed. After you close this window, we'll allow you to file a bug report using the intergrated bug reporting tool. This will gather information about your system and your installtion process. The details will be sent to our bug tracker and a developer will attend to the problem as soon as possible."

This happens every time when I try to install Lubuntu or Ubuntu MATE. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And this came out of the boot repair disk: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12366044/

I'm sorry for massive amounts of messages but I have low character limit.